# xlsm file converting to csv file with integer value

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, type-conversion, xlsm

In excel file (with macro) to cells I'm writing integer value 1, 3, and so on. Than, i converting this file to csv format with this code:

```
class ExcelToCsvConvert:
@staticmethod
def makeCsv():
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('csv_file.xlsm')
    for sheet in workbook.sheets():
        with open('{}.csv'.format(sheet.name), 'w', newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            for row in range(sheet.nrows):
                out = []
                for cell in sheet.row_values(row):
                    try:
                        out.append(cell.decode('utf-8'))
                    except:
                        out.append(cell)
                #out[4] = int(out[4])
                print(out[4])
                writer.writerow(out)
```

And some value (`print(out)`) are printing something like: `'1.0', '3.0'` where i need integer value (`1 , 3`). Without `.0`

How to do that, or, what I'm doing wrong ?

---

Ok, i solved with this loop:

```
if ".0" in str(cell)[-2:]:
   cell = str(cell)[:-2]
```

Comment: Do you need to store the values as integers to do something with them, or just print them out as integers?

Comment: Try converting `cell` to `int` and handle a `ValueError`. But keep in mind that if you have `floats`, then you'll end up losing some data.

Comment: I need to store this values as integer

Comment: @Luk, by default `xlrd` reads numbers as `floats`, so you are likely to end with both `floats` and 'integers' being read in as `floats`. The best thing you can do here is figure out which columns need to be converted as `integers` and convert them to `integer` before outputting them to the csv file. Question: are there any columns from the excel file that are `floats`?

Comment: In default cells were float, I chcanged that to integer/string/standard ... but python always  read and shoing me as float value :(

maybe this code is guilty:

`quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL` or 
`cell.decode('utf-8')`